# Creating a bidirectional rule in CHR and CLP/FD

Tags: prolog, clpfd, constraint-handling-rules

As an example. Suppose that everything which is red has value 5. I write the following:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

:- chr_type color ---> red ; blue.

:- chr_constraint hasColor(?any, ?color).
:- chr_constraint hasValue(?any, ?int).

hasColor(Thing, red) <=> hasValue(Thing, X), X #= 5.
hasColor(Thing, blue) <=> hasValue(Thing, X), X #\= 5.
```

`hasColor(moose, red)` correctly produces the inferenced output `hasColor(moose, red), hasValue(moose, 5)`.

However, I would then like the inference to work the other way too; to specify that if something has value 5, it must be red. Currently, `hasValue(moose, 5)` is accepted as a constraint but produces no inference. But adding the rule:

`hasValue(Thing, 5) ==> hasColor(Thing, red).`

causes any invocation of `hasValue(moose, 5)` to lock up completely and stack overflow, apparently causing an infinite loop, even though `==>` states that the rule "calls its body exactly once".

I appreciate that I have not stated that a Thing can have only one color or value (I am not sure how I would do this), but repeatedly adding the constraint that `moose` is `red` and has value `5` should surely not change the constraint set.

How can I enable the system to perform this inference correctly in both directions?

Comment: This is a [cross-posting](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/creating-a-bidirectional-rule-in-chr-and-clpfd/1550).

Comment: I did post it on the SWI forums as well because it was quiet here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).
:- chr_type color ---> red ; blue.

:- chr_constraint thing_color_value(?any, ?color, ?int).

thing_color_value(T,red,V) <=> var(V)|thing_color_value(T,red,5).
thing_color_value(T,C,5) <=> var(C)|thing_color_value(T,red,5).
```

Comment: This does work in both cases presented, but it would be nice to be able to do it without having to combine everything in one predicate, since I expect that in the final system there would be a large number of constraints interacting. In addition, `thing_color_value moose,blue,X` only leaves X unbound, rather than applying the CLPFD constraint that X is not 5 as the original does.

Comment: The thing is because you are modeling a relationship between three variables I think it make sense to have them in one term/constraint. But I am not a CHR expert so there might be other ways to do it ..I did not model the blue constraint  because I didn't think that was a central part of the question..

Comment: It makes sense. But in the full system there could be 20 variables. And no problem. I want to derive the most precise set of constraints.